# Angular 5.2: Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="1.25rem" - from platform-browser.js

Tags: node.js, angular, svg, safari, node-modules

I am getting the following Console Error in my Safari browser for Angular 5.2 App. It is coming from node_modules `platform-browser.js`. And related to svg height setting.
Is it like ‘rem’ heights not accepted for svg in Safari browser?

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="1.25rem"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Nowhere this error is listed. I would like to know exact reason behind this. But this error does not stop the execution of pages.
Node version is: 8.10.0

Note: In chrome browser I am not getting this error.

Comment: rem is probably not supported. It's not part of SVG 1.1 and coverage of SVG 2 is incomplete in all browsers.

Comment: Yes, may be rem values not supported in all browsers.  But manually I am not assigning any rem values to svg attrs. I have that values in 2-3 places in html, I tested removing that, still same error.